# Hardware Floating Point Square Root

Tags: math, floating-point, verilog, ieee-754, square-root

How do hardware implementations of a floating-point square root work? Which algorithm would they use and can anyone provide links to verilog/vhdl implementations?

Comment: Have you looked for an integer square root? You could use it by shifting to get an even exponent, then dividing that exponent by two.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, either a digit-recurrence algorithm (little resource) or Newton's iteration on the reciprocal square root (needs other operators: adder, multiplier, or FMA).

Concerning Newton's iteration, the choice of the initial approximation is not obvious. See Kornerup and Muller's article [*Choosing starting values for certain Newton–Raphson iterations*](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/TCSNewton.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You get the best bang for the money by implementing an approximation for 1 / sqrt (x) in hardware, giving maybe ten or twelve bits of precision, like Intel processors do. Then you use good old Newton iteration to improve that approximation using add/subtract/multiply only, and multiply the last approximation by x.

Alternatively, consider that calculating the square root of x is the same as dividing x by the square root of x. You can implement something very similar to a division, giving one bit of precision each time, except that the number you are dividing by changes in every iteration.